# Access Denied for VS2013 MVC 5 "No Auth" project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-express

I've created a new MVC 5 test project in Visual Studio 2013 with authentication set to "No Authentication".

When I go to run the site in IE under Debug, I get Access Denied error.

I've confirmed the following:

-Visual Studio is running in Admin mode

-debugger is using IISExpress

-Project properties: Windows Authentication is set to 'false' and Anonymous Authentication is set to 'true

-applicationhost.config: the system.webServer subtree reflects the above:

```
<location path="DeleteMe">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Other facts:
-I do have another MVC 5 website that does use WA. However, I don't see how this could possibly affect a completely independent project?

I've checked all related posts, and nothing is working to fix this.

Please help!